# How to interrupt a long discussion on HF politely?

Tags: procedure

In my city there is a local amateur radio "club". People gather every morning on 7.135 and chat. I was invited by one of the members of this club to join. Turned out that people can chat on this frequency for a very long time without any pauses or naming their call signs.

What is the most common way to let people know that I'm here and would like to join? Currently I briefly name my call sign and it seems to work. However I don't know whether this is the right way to do it.

Comment: If that works, maybe use that method to ask? Anyway, Amateur bands are supposed to be shared medium, so aside from the interpersonal aspect, you might not want to develop a shyness to use that medium.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stating your call in the brief pause between transmissions is accepted procedure. It seems brief and rude by normal social convention, but it's necessary on the radio since anything longer might not be heard by the other stations involved in the conversation.

One of the other stations should acknowledge you and give you an opportunity to speak. It's at that time you can say "thanks".